# Running Django in docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem starting a django project inside a docker container. My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM python:2.7
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

The `requirements.txt` consists of the single line `Django` which install django successfully.

My `docker-compose.yml` has the following content:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - ./web:/code
```

To create a project I am calling:

```
docker-compose run web python django-admin.py startproject web .
```

which crashes with the following message:

```
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also this

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject web .
```

crashes with

```
ERROR: Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"django-admin.py\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

It seems to me that there is an error in the `$PATH` when executing the container like this. When I use the interactive mode `-it`, I am able to call the `django-admin` from this folder. Is the `PATH` not set correctly or am I doing something else wrong here? The `Dockerfile` is in the directory `web`.

Edit: After the suggestion in the comment, I tried to run the `django-admin` with the full path:

```
root@935ca5543589:/code# which django-admin
/usr/local/bin/django-admin
```

Still no change:

```
docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/django-admin startproject web .
ERROR: Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/local/bin/django-admin\": stat /usr/local/bin/django-admin: no such file or directory"
```

Comment: Why don't you try to use the full path to `django-admin`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still no success. But again the same behavior, when I logon onto the container, it works...

Comment: Are you trying to execute `django-admin` or `django-admin.py` ?

Comment: Yes. Same thing. Both ways work now. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple actually. I had an error in my `Dockerfile` when I ran the project first. After changing the `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose` did not rebuild the image automatically which I was assuming. Even rebuilding with `docker build` did not solve this. Only after deleting the whole image, a rebuild was forced and gave me the correct result.

Comment: Why the downvote? This clearly solves my problem and I described how to do it.

Comment: idk, it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

**What I ran :**

```
docker-compose run app djando-admin.py startproject app
```

**Output:**

> sh: djando-admin.py: not found

**Solution:**

```
sudo docker-compose run app django-admin startproject app .
```

Try to use `sudo`.

Comment: for future readers ~> **docker-compose run django django-admin startproject core .**