# Unable to create a container for a Django app

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was trying to make a basic container as a learning project that should download Django from PyPI and run the default server. For that I made 3 files i.e.

### `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY /requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

### `requirements.txt`

```
Django==4.0
```

the command that I used in terminal and the output are given below in the terminal snippet:

```
samar@wasseypur:~/Desktop/project2/telusko$ sudo docker-compose run web django-admin startproject mysite .
[sudo] password for samar: 
Creating telusko_web_run ... done
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "django-admin": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: 1
```

Comment: Try running `docker-compose build` first.  `docker-compose run ...` doesn't automatically rebuild your image if your dockerfile changes, so you may be using an image was built from a previous (broken) version of your dockerfile.  See here: [Running Django in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196188/running-django-in-docker-compose)